# Shell program doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For multiple folders provided as input from the user, I'd like to count how many of the files and folders they contain have different permission settings as the container folder itself.

I've written the following shell code.  Why does it display the rights, but not count anything?

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ! -d $1 ]
 then echo $1 nu este director
  exit1
fi 
ls -R $1 >temp
permission= ls -al $1 | cut -d" " -f1   
for i in `cat temp`
do 
  perm= ls -l $i | cut -d" " -f1  
if [ $permission -ne $perm ] 
   then n=`expr $n + 1`
fi
echo   $n
done
```

Answer (score 1):

- You shouldn't use `-ne` for string comparisons. You need to do this:

  ```
  if [ "$permission" != "$perm" ] 
  then 
      n=`expr $n + 1`
  fi
  ```
- You need to initialise `n` before you can increment it.

  ```
  n=0
  ```
- You need to fix your command substitution:

  ```
  permission=$(ls -al $1 | cut -d" " -f1)  
  perm=$(ls -l $i | cut -d" " -f1)
  ```
- `exit1` should be `exit 1`

Answer (score 0):

you want to use command substitution:

```
permission=$(ls -al $1 | cut -d" " -f1)
# ...
perm=$(ls -l $i | cut -d" " -f1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing your variable `$n`, so your call to `expr` expands to `expr + 1` which is a syntax error. You should see lots of "expr: syntax error" messages on `stderr`. Just add the line `n=0` before your loop and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to other's answers:

`exit1` should be `exit 1`